# Ignore all files except in subfolder

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a git repo with many files and folder but I want to ignore everything except files and folders in a src folder.

This is my .gitignore:

```
/*

!**/src/
!.gitignore
!README.md
```

But this is what git status returns:

```
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .gitignore
        README.md

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

So it seems that it is ignoring everything including my src folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to ignore files only, not folders:

```
*
!*/
```

[It is not possible  to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309) (even with 2.7 in your case)

Then you can exclude the folder src files and subfolders content:

```
!**/src/**
```

Comment: Omg, thanks so much! This was killing me and I thought it was something simple. Do you need to do !**/src/** ? can't you just do !**/src to include the whole folder?

Comment: @NecroTheif `!**/src` would not work, as its content would still be ignored by '`*`'. (I just tested it)

Comment: Wow, this really works. I have tried many other answers, but none of them really work.